# Refresh dataGridView after update from client pc

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I'm making a LAN based system wherein once the PC2 clicked the served button in its datagridview (ONLY STATUS WHICH HAS `PREPARING` VALUES WILL BE DISPLAYED IN THE DGV), the item that was clicked will be removed from the datagrid and update it's database status from `PREPARING` to `SERVED`.

How can I make it to auto-refresh my datagridview to PC1 when changes has been made to my database from PC2, or vice versa?

Please take note that I did not used binding datasource or anything since I'm not really familiar with that..

[image]

CODE:

```
public void fillGrid()
    {

        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT progressID, receiptNo, time, item, quantity, tableNo FROM tblprogress WHERE status = 'Preparing' ORDER BY time ASC");
        cmd.Connection = dbConn;
        dgvProgress.Rows.Clear();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            dgvProgress.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4], rdr[5]);
            dgvProgress.ClearSelection();

        }

        rdr.Close();
    }
```

---

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProgress.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Status")
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tblprogress SET status = 'Served' WHERE progressID = " + dgvProgress.CurrentRow.Cells["progressID"].Value.ToString() + "");
            cmd.Connection = dbConn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dgvProgress.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it such that the changes have a timestamp. Then use a timer and check at a specified interval if the timestamp of the data you have is the same as in the database. If not then pull the data from the database and update the datagridviewer